# How to prove this equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

How would one go about proving this is an equivalence relation? I have no idea where to start.

$\cal R$ is the relation on $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$, such that $((a, b),(c, d)) \in \cal  R$ if and only if $a−d = c−b$.

Comment: As for where to start, begin with the definition. FYI: This relation is the same as having $a+b=c+d$, i.e. pairs with the same entry sum. For any integer $n$ there is a line $x+y=n$ that defines an equivalence class.

Answer (score 0):

If function $f:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb Z$ is prescribed by $(a,b)\mapsto a+b$ then $$((a,b),(c,d))\in\mathcal R\iff f(a,b)=f(c,d)$$
This makes it easy to prove that the relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive:

- $f(a,b)=f(a,b)$
- $f(a,b)=f(a',b')\Rightarrow f(a',b')=f(a,b)$
- $f(a,b)=f(a',b')\wedge f(a',b')=f(a'',b'')\Rightarrow f(a,b)=f(a'',b'')$